# BeautifulSoup4をimport出来ない。

Tags: python, windows-10, beautifulsoup, python-idle

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` をIDLE(3.7.0)shellで実行すると、以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\（ユーザー名）\Desktop\python スクリプト\test\scraper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

コマンドプロンプトで`python --version`でバージョンを確認すると、python3.7.0と表示されます。

`pip install beautifulsoup4`でbeautifulsoupをインストールし直すと、以下のように表示されます。

```
C:\Users\（ユーザー名）\Desktop\python>pip install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/0a/47fdf541c97fd9b6a610cb5fd518175308a7cc60569962e776ac52420387/beautifulsoup4-4.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (90kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 610kB/s
**tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.15.2 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.4.3 which is incompatible.**
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.3
```

**追加**
これらを実行した後で、`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`を実行しても同じエラーが発生するということです。
質問がわかりずらく、すみませんでした。
pip freeze　のリストには　beautifulsoup4==4.6.3　の表記があります。
以下が　`pip show beautifulsoup4`　の実行結果です。

```
C:\Users\（ユーザー名）\Desktop\python>pip show beautifulsoup4
Name: beautifulsoup4
Version: 4.6.3
Summary: Screen-scraping library
Home-page: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/
Author: Leonard Richardson
Author-email: leonardr@segfault.org
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\（ユーザー名）\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: conda-build
```

以下が、IDLE上での　`import sys; print(sys.path, sys.executable)`　の実行結果です。

```
['C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\Desktop\\python スクリプト\\test', 'C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37', 'C:\\Users\\（ユーザー名）\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages'] C:\Users\（ユーザー名）\Desktop\python スクリプト\test\pythonw.exe
```

Comment: 確認させて頂きたいのですが、`pip install beautifulsoup4` を実行した後でも bs4 のインポートに失敗するということでしょうか？　おそらくそのあたりに齟齬があるような気がしています。

Comment: そうです。理解していただきありがとうございます

Comment: IDLE 上で `import sys; print(sys.path, sys.executable)` の1行を実行した結果を質問文に追記して頂けませんか？（ユーザー名の部分は編集して頂いて大丈夫です）　質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記ができます。

Answer (score 1):

前半のエラー、「ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'」は、beautifleSoap4のモジュールがインストールできていないというエラーです。後半で、`pip install beautifulsoup4`でインストールして、`Successfully`のメッセージが出ているので、`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`は使えるようになっていると思われます。

恐らく以下のメッセージが気になっての質問と思われますが、これはwarningなので`beautifulsoup4`のインストールは完了しています。

```
**tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.15.2 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.4.3 which is incompatible.**
```

このwarningは、`numpy`をアップグレードして`numpy-1.15.2`にしたので、`tensorflow 1.10.0`の依存関係 numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3 と合わなくなったためです。ワーニングを解消するためには、`tensorflow`の方では`tensorflow 1.11.0`が公開されているので、`tensorflow`をアップグレードするのが一つの方法です。ただし、python3.7用の`tensorflow`のバイナリーはまだないので、単純に`pip install tensorflow`ではインストールすることはできません。

事情があって`tensorflow`をアップグレードできない場合は、`numpy`をダウングレードします。ダウングレードの方法は、以下のようにして、requirementを満たすバージョンを指定してインストールします。

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.14.5
```

また、プロジェクトの数が増えていくと、システムの site ディレクトリにすべてのパッケージをインストールしていると、パッケージの衝突はよく起こることなので、そうなってくると仮想環境を作る方がいいです。特に`tensorflow`のように依存関係が厳しい場合には、仮想環境を作成してインストールすることを勧めます。

Python チュートリアル: [12. 仮想環境とパッケージ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/venv.html)

**追加**
現在でも、bs4 のインポートに失敗するということであれば、`pip install beautifulsoup4`を実行した場所で、次のコマンドを実行して`beautifulsoup4`がその一覧に含まれているかどうか確認してください。

```
pip freeze
```

`beautifulsoup4`が一覧に含まれている場合は、次のコマンドを実行して、その結果を追記していただけないでしょうか。`Location`の場所を知りたいです。

```
pip show beautifulsoup4
```

それと、コメントにある、`import sys; print(sys.path, sys.executable)`の出力と付き合わせると原因が分かる可能性が高いです。

質問への追記から判断すると、原因は、`pip install beautifulsoup4`でインストールされた場所はAnaconda3の方で、python3.7の方ではなかったことです。

複数のpythonをインストールしている場合は、パスが通っていない方のPythonにpipでインストールする場合には、どのPythonかを指定しないといけなくなります。

一つの方法は、IDLE 上で pip を実行させることです。

```
>>> import pip._internal as pip
>>> pip.main(['install','beautifulsoup4'])
```

また、多分以下のコマンドでも`python3.7`にインストールできると思います。

```
py -3.7 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

python3.7のpython.exeのパスを指定して実行することでもできます。

```
pathtopython/python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

なお、Anaconda3をインストールしているのであれば、Anaconda3付属のSpyderの方を使った方が簡単かもしれません。

Comment: ではなぜプログラムは正しく実行されないのでしょうか。

Comment: 正しく実行されない原因ですが、追記しましたので、コメントとあわせて質問に追記していただければと思います。

Comment: 質問が追加されたので、回答を追加しておきました。